# Recreating sentences with numbers

Tags: python

So I have developed a code which lets you recreate a sentence but there is one problem,it cuts out a word! I don't know why so if somebody can correct it that would be brilliant thanks!

```
Sentence = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
Sen = Sentence.split()
remove=(",")

numbers = input("Enter Numbers(Separating them with a comma for example 1,3,2): ")

newnumbers = ""
for char in numbers:

    if char not in remove:

        newnumbers = newnumbers + char + " "
numlist = newnumbers.split()

length = len(numlist) -1

del numlist[length]

savenum = " ".join(numlist) -1

file = open("Bruh.txt","w")
file.write(Sentence)
file.write("\n"+savenum)
file.close()

newli = []

for char in numlist:

    newnum = (int(char)-1) 
    newli = newli + [Sen[int(newnum)]]
words = " ".join(newli)

print("Original Sentence: ",Sentence)
print("Recreated Sentence: ", words)
```

Answer (score 1):

These lignes are responsible for that behaviour :

```
# length = len(numlist) -1 # <==== comment these lines
# del numlist[length]  # <==== comment these lines
```

Put them in comments, or remove them :

```
Sentence = input("Please enter a sentence: ")
Sen = Sentence.split()
remove=(",")

numbers = input("Enter Numbers(Separating them with a comma for example 1,3,2): ")

newnumbers = ""
for char in numbers:

    if char not in remove:

        newnumbers = newnumbers + char + " "
numlist = newnumbers.split()

# length = len(numlist) -1 # <==== comment these lines
# del numlist[length]  # <==== comment these lines

savenum = " ".join(numlist) -1

file = open("Bruh.txt","w")
file.write(Sentence)
file.write("\n"+savenum)
file.close()

newli = []

for char in numlist:

    newnum = (int(char)-1) 
    newli = newli + [Sen[int(newnum)]]
words = " ".join(newli)

print("Original Sentence: ",Sentence)
print("Recreated Sentence: ", words)
```

Comment: This was a template I got so I am not too sure how the code words xP